# How to include and execute JavaScript in Django templates?

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I've read many other questions and answers, and of course the documentation. However, I still can't make my JS code run inside my templates.

base.html

```
{% load static %}
{% load i18n %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>{% block title %}{% translate "DaniMundo" %}{% endblock title %}</title>
<link href="{% static 'css/default.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<aside>
{% include "navigation.html" %}
</aside>
<main>
{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
</main>

<script src="{% static 'js/clipboard.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/custom.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

blog/article_details.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load custom_filters %}

{% block title %}{{ article.title }} | {{ block.super }}{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<article>
<header>
<h1 class="title">{{ article.title }}</h1>
<p>{% translate "Date of publication:" %} {{ article.date_created }}</p>
<p>{% include "blog/article_authors.html" %}</p>
</header>
<p class="summary">{{ article.summary }}</p>
{{ article.body|markdown|safe }}
{% if article.date_updated != article.date_created %}<p>{% translate "Last update:" %} {{ article.date_updated }}</p>{% endif %}<hr />
<div class="comments">
{% include "blog/comments.html" with article_path=article.get_absolute_url article_slug=article|full_slug %}
</div>
</article>
{% endblock content %}
```

custom.js

```js
function checkAnswer(origin) {
var question_name = $(origin).attr("data-question");
var correct_answer_element = $(origin).attr("data-correct");
var correct_answer_id = $("#"+correct_answer_element).val();
var correct_answer_label = $("label[for="+correct_answer_id+"]").text();
var chosen_answer_id = $("input[name="+question_name+"]:checked").attr("id");
var chosen_answer_label = $("label[for="+chosen_answer_id+"]").text();
if(correct_answer_id == chosen_answer_id) {
alert("Bravo!");
}
else {
alert("Hmmm... no. \n" + correct_answer_label);
}
$("input[name="+question_name+"]").attr("disabled", true);
}
```

As you probably expect, **comments.html** contains the disqus script. That also fails. I tried to copy **custom.js**'s content directly to the end of both **base.html** and **article_details.html**, nothing changed.

For the sake of completeness, I'd mention that the `origin` in **custom.js** refers to a button which looks like this:

```html
<button data-question="question1" data-correct="question1_correct" onclick="checkAnswer(this)">Answer</button>
```

So, how should I get JS code to run in Django templates?

Comment: You probably have a js error so prevent to run other codes. Check browser consol

Comment: Are you  sure that jquery loaded successfully?

Comment: did you slove problem?

Comment: Hello, I managed to solve it. The whole problem was caused by the lack of single quotes around the value of the for parameter in the jQuery selector. I will also put it as an answer, but in short: 
`var correct_answer_label = $("label[for='"+correct_answer_id+"']").text();`

Answer (score 0):

As always in this situations where something which should work simply doesn't, it was a simple error. The `for` value (and any other attribute value, by the way) must be quoted in the jQuery selectors in **custom.js**.

```js
function checkAnswer(origin, correct_answer_message="Great!", wrong_answer_message="Hmmm... no.") {
    var question_name = $(origin).attr("data-question");
    var correct_answer_element = $(origin).attr("data-correct");
    var correct_answer_id = $("#"+correct_answer_element).val();
    var correct_answer_label = $("label[for='"+correct_answer_id+"']").text();
    var chosen_answer_id = $("input[name='"+question_name+"']:checked").attr("id");
    var chosen_answer_label = $("label[for='"+chosen_answer_id+"']").text();
    if(correct_answer_id == chosen_answer_id) {
        alert(correct_answer_message);
    }
    else {
        alert(wrong_answer_message + " \n" + correct_answer_label);
    }
    $("input[name="+question_name+"]").attr("disabled", true);
}
```

As you can see if you compare this function with the one from the qestion text, it now accepts two optional parameters - `correct_answer_message` and `wrong_answer_message`. Those have nothing to do with this question, but my function looks like this right now and I just wanted to show a working example which solved the problem.

Of course, the disqus script now works, too. :)